# Is there any command available in Google cloud CLI to list the filenames that are created/Updated in Google bucket on a 'specific date’?

Tags: command-line, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I am new to the Google cloud, I would like to List only specific dated files from google bucket. Do we have any commands available in Google Cloud CLI to list files from Google bucket on a 'specific date'?

I have files in GCS bucket overwritten by the owner everyday at specific time. If anything fails at GCS side I don't want to run my ETL job because there is no new file has been generated in GCS side. To continue my ETL process, I would like to retrieve either the create date of the each file in GCS bucket or the current dated files in Google cloud storage bucket.Is there any command that's available in GCS CLI ? To build my process I would like to know options available in GCS CLI. Please suggest.

Answer (score 4):

The new [`gcloud storage`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/storage) command can do it:

```
gcloud storage objects list --filter="timeCreated>20220817T00:00:00 and timeCreated<20220818T00:00:00" --format="value(name)" gs://BUCKET/
```

You can also filter on `updated`. See docs on [filters](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/filters) and [formats](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/formats) to get the exact output you want.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is in-built filter option. One solution is to list the files and grep the required date or parse the list further with pipe `(|)` command to filter the files with exact criteria - something like below

```
gsutil ls -l gs://your-bucket/ | grep 2022-12-15
```

Print filtered filenames:

```
gsutil ls -l gs://your-bucket/ | grep 2022-12-15 | awk '{print $3}'
```